# How to prevent XSS in attributes

Tags: php, html, xss, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

so I have a site where users can register using a username of their choosing and can submit large blocks of text and add comments. Currently, to avert XSS, I use strip_tags on the data on input to the database and I only output the data in the body, rather than in an attribute.
I'm currently making changes to the site, one of which is to make a user page which is loaded when someone clicks on the username (a link). This would look like:

```
<a href="example.com/user/<?php echo $username; ?>">...</a>
```

I'm worried that for the $username variable, someone could insert

```
<a href="example.com/user/user" onClick="javascript:alert('XSS');">...</a>
```

I've read a bunch of the other SO posts on this, but none gave a black-and-white answer. If I use the following on all text on output, in addition to strip_tags on input:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

is that going to be enough to stop all XSS attacks, including those using the inline `javascript:` syntax?

Also, is there any way to remove actual html tags without removing things like "Me > you"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping depends on the context. If it's a URL, use URL encoding (%xx), but also check that the full URL does not start with "javascript:". Your syntax for the onclick-attribute is not required. Onclick is a javascript event handler, so any javascript inside it will run.

See the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat sheet to see how to escape for different contexts.

Comment: If, for example, my code is:

$user = 'asdf" onClick="alert(\'XSS\');"';
echo '<a href="/user/$user">...</a>';

It would result in <a href="/user/asdf" onClick="alert('XSS');">
So the PHP function urlencode($user) would fix this?

Comment: Test it and see? :-)
<a href="/user/asdf%22+onClick%3D%22alert%28%27XSS%27%29%3B%22">...</a>

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP5 Certification Study guide, there are two golden rules about security:

1. Filter input
2. Escape output

At the moment you are only looking at one side of the problem.

But I would prefer htmlentities.

Comment: Why use htmlentities vs. htmlspecialchars?

Comment: "This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities." These is also the preferred escaping method for Zend. According to the above mentioned study guide.

Comment: I understand the difference, I just mean is there any real reason to use one over the other?

Comment: No one, which I really experienced. But in my opinion, sometimes it is just useful to listen to other's advice.